# URI link is not opening on browser through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

My intent is not opening and showing `FatalException` Error. I am requesting a browser to open the link but it's not working and I am unable to find the `error`.

```
public void searchQuestion(View view) {
    String queryString = search_input.getText().toString();

    Log.d(TAG, "searchQuestion: "+ search_input.getText());

    Uri buildURI = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARM, queryString)
            .build();
    Log.d("buildURI", "getBookInfo: " + buildURI);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(buildURI));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: There may not be anything that supports `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`, and that is the wrong way to create [an `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH). If you want to use that `Uri`, use `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`.

Comment: Thanks! then when ACTION_WEB_SEARCH will be supported ?

Comment: It will depend on whether the user has a browser or other app installed that offers support for that `Intent` action. I rarely hear of it being used, so it would not surprise me if not all devices support it. And, even if a user does have support... your particular `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` was broken. If you read [the documentation for that `Intent` action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH), you will see that it does not take a `Uri`. Your query goes in an `Intent` extra instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ACTION_VIEW` instead of `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(buildURI));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

For more information https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH

Comment: Then where do we use `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`?